# Passing (laravel) Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I want to pass/store Laravel array in JavaScript variable. I used `->all()` so I get the result like this rather than object:

```
array:83 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 11
  2 => 12
  ...
]
```

I can access this in view using `{{ $theArray }}`.

However whatever I tried, I couldn't make this to javascript array.

I tried

`var array = {{ $theArray }};`

`var array = {{{ $theArray }}};`

I feel like I'm close but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
var app = @json($array);
```

Works like a charm

Comment: your answer was flagged as low quality because of length.  Consider expanding your answer to explain how it works.

Comment: Your answer is the most concise and works like the others. Don't know why it' not the selected answer. What @DerekBrown said doesn't makes sense, as the other answers also doesn't explain how works.

Comment: Thumps up for this answer. It uses the laravel blade directive instead of the manual way above.

Comment: I learnig more one method fantastic, thanks friend work with charm

Comment: its working .. as its predefine method in laravel for javascript

Comment: @MateusFelipe it was not selected answer because the OP was from 2015 and this answer is 2018, that's a nice way, and that's the version I use now everyday. Fyi, I marked it as selected answer :)

Comment: Yes! This is the perfect solution for passing a Laravel array directly through to javascript

Answer (score 30):

you can use **[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

```
var array = {{ json_encode($theArray) }};
```

or parse the json string using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```
var array = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($theArray) }}');
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I got `Unexpected token` if using this {{  }}. then I change to {!!  !!} then this will work. maybe cuz of laravel version

Comment: {{ }} will escape the output string, hence the error. while {!! !!} doesn't, it outputs the string as is. check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 21):

This works for me :)

```
var array =  {!! json_encode($theArray) !!};
```

Comment: worked well for me. You could also use blade helper @json($theArray) . still works the same

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of rendering it as JSON in order to initialize a JavaScript variable. For example:

```
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

However, instead of manually calling `json_encode`, you may use the `@json` Blade directive. The  `@json` directive accepts the same arguments as PHP's `json_encode` function:

```
<script>
    var app = @json($array);

    var app = @json($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</script>
```

The `@json` directive is also useful for seeding Vue components or data-* attributes:

```
<example-component :some-prop='@json($array)'></example-component>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Answer (score 3):

you have enclodse with quotes,or use json_encode()

```
var array = "{{ $theArray }}";
            ^               ^
```

or, if the value in an `array()`

```
var array = "{{ json_encode($theArray) }}";
            ^                            ^
```

Without having quotes around javascript variable, it will throw you error. you can check in your console.

Comment: `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me.

`let array = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($array) !!}');`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `all()` is not enough to convert your [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections) to array. I encountered this issue trying to pass the collection of custom type objects to JS via Laravel view.

To get the array on the front end JS you have to apply [`Collection::values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-values) method before [`all()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-all) method.

So:

```php
// In your HTTP controller
$collection = collect([myObj1,myObj2]); // The collection filled with custom type objects.

$myArray = $collection->values()->all(); // Then converted to an array. Just `all()` is not enough;

return view('myview', $myArray);
```

```html
{{-- In your myview.blade.php --}}

<script>window.myArray= @json($myArray)</script>
```

Then in your JS `window.myArray` you get an array `[]`, not an object `{}`.

**A Bit Of Details**

This is probably happens due to the fact that when an array indexes are not ascending ordered PHP considers the indexes to be object keys, then it considers the array to be an object. Thus the transformation to an object instead of an array. Laravel collection `values()` resets the array keys. I suspect it applies PHP [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed a Laravel Collection to pass through as an iterable array on the JavaScript client. The following worked:

```
return array_values($job_summaries->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the blade directive `@json` was the simplest thing that worked for me.

```
<script>
    var jsArray = JSON.parse(@json($phpArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
</script>
```

Here is the full list of parameters for `@json` and `json_encode` https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

- Both `jsArray` and `JSON.parse()` are javascript
- The blade directive is `@json()`
- No curly braces needed with directives

Answer (score -1):

Simply, escape the special characters using the blade syntax. Try this.

```
var array = {!! $theArray !!};
```

Best part, you don't need to parse it to its object form in JavaScript.