# How to use js to get all array value from my database

Tags: javascript, laravel

1, This js only take 1st array value

2, i use foreach should be take all the value

3, im confuse Please Helps

```js
<script>

var unit_balance = 
  @foreach ($bike as $value)
    [{{ $value->unit_balance }}];
  @endforeach

function myFunction(){
  var totalLessThan20 = unit_balance.filter(unit => unit <= 20);
  if(totalLessThan20.length) {
   alert("Some of unit left is less than 20. Please restock immediately!");
  }
}
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only `unit_balance` values in array then, use this

```
<script>
    var unit_balance = {{json_encode($bike->pluck("unit_balance"))}}
</script>
```

or if you want whole array as it is in js then remove `pluck` from above code, like this

```
<script>
    var unit_balance = {{json_encode($bike)}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var unit_balance = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($bike->unit_balance ) }}');
```

Refer [Passing (laravel) Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326699/passing-laravel-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest that you paste here the result of `dd($bike);` to check that it's has the iterable structure you expect.

The suggested

```
const unitBalance = JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($bike->unit_balance ) }}');
```

is a good solution