# How to use JS value in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to access js value in script of laravel blade.

here is my script

```
$(document).change('#category', function () {
    var val = $('#category').val();

    var x = {{ $categories->where('parent_id', val)->get() }}; //here I want to keep val variable

    console.log(x);
});
```

this way I accessed main Category in select tag

```
@foreach($categories->whereNull('parent_id')->get() as $row)
      <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

In same way I want to filter by parent_id using Jquery and set it to the child category, This $category is the collections of data that I get from the controller.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: it doesn't work like this ... blade is compiled into regular php, that is all executed and returned to the browser ... THEN javascript runs ... big difference between server side code and front side code

Comment: I think there is a way to replace the variable in laravel syntex in script? Do you have any Idea with this?

Comment: should I use ajax for this purpose?

Comment: if you need data back from the server you wont have much choice otherwise, unless you wanted to output all your categories into a javascript array and search through them in javascript

Comment: I have an array of category already passes from controller just need to filter them using jquery. That's why i need this js var. I don't need any data back from server side.

Comment: then you don't need to involve blade there ... you need to do this all in javascript, you are not doing the filtering on the server side

Comment: yeah right. Can you please tell me the way how can I filter this inside jquery?

Comment: this way I accessed category in select tag to make options. Now I want this in same way using jquery

`@foreach($categories->whereNull('parent_id')->get() as $row)
        <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
@endforeach`

Comment: Please Check my edited question

Comment: You could groupBy with parent_id in laravel and store that as a javascript array then get the values from that array when selecting.

Comment: can You please give me a code as a  example?

Comment: You can see how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326699/passing-laravel-array-in-javascript). Also you might need to convert that laravel collection into array if it doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby) is an example of how to use groupBy with laravel collection.

Comment: ok thanks. I am checking your suggestion.

Comment: In blade template you would do this: `var x = @json($categories->groupBy('parent_id')->toArray());` and access those like this: `var categoriesWithParentId = x[val];`

Answer (score 0):

if you have an external js file, just create a function that receives parameters, and in the blade view, call it and pass parameters.
For example:

Js file:

```
function hello(name){
   alert(name)
}
```

Blade file:

```
<button onclick="hello({{ $name }})">Click me</button>
```

And if the script is inside the blade view, just use this:

```
alert({{ $name }})
```

But sadly, you can`t access js variables from laravel the normal way, and you don't need to! there's a huge difference between front end and backend.

Comment: It can't be the solution for this. I have to make it possible using Ajax.