# How to divide multi array in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have an array that has 3 data in each index
**variable**

```
var data = @json($data)
```

**output**

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {day: "Saturday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 300}
1: {day: "Sunday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0}
2: {day: "Monday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0}
3: {day: "Tuesday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0}
4: {day: "Wednesday", totalIncome: 500, totalExpense: 0}
5: {day: "Thursday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0}
length: 6
```

I want to make 3 array like

```
var days = datas.day;
var incomes = datas.totalIncome;
var expenses = data.totalExpenses;
```

what should I do now to make this 3 arrays from data. please help

Comment: `var data = @json($data)` doesn't look like valid JS?

Comment: it's valid for laravel php. php array to js array conversion

Comment: So what's the javascript tag for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326699/passing-laravel-array-in-javascript

Comment: you can find your answer from this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this in vanilla JS:

```
const days = [], incomes = [], expenses = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    days.push(data[i]["day"]);
    incomes.push(data[i]["totalIncome"]);
    expenses.push(data[i]["totalExpense"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map your data into new arrays.

```
var days = datas.map(function(obj) {
    return obj['day'];
});
var incomes = datas.map(function(obj) {
    return obj['income'];
});
var expenses = datas.map(function(obj) {
    return obj['expenses'];
});
```

If you have `lodash` installed.

```
var days = _.pluck(datas, 'day')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use native `flatMap` function, for example:

```js
    var groupBy = key => {
        return [
           {day: "Saturday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 300},
           {day: "Sunday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0},
           {day: "Monday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0},
           {day: "Tuesday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0},
           {day: "Wednesday", totalIncome: 500, totalExpense: 0},
           {day: "Thursday", totalIncome: 0, totalExpense: 0}
        ].flatMap(v => v[key])
    }


    const days = groupBy('day')
    console.log(days)
```